# DataBinding with entityframework bug

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, data-binding, ado.net

I have an application which consists of simple schema of DB:

Networks 1-->* Shops

i use entityframework (Default EntityObject Code Generator) with winforms,
i use DataBinding to a grid to CUD these entities,
i have :

```
    DbObjectModelContainer _context = new DbObjectModelContainer();

    _context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;

    NetworkBindingSource.DataSource = _context.Networks;     

    ShopsBindingSource.DataSource = NetworkBindingSource;

    ShopsBindingSource.DataMember = "Shops";

    NetworkBindingNavigator.BindingSource = NetworkBindingSource;

    ShopBindingNavigator.BindingSource = ShopsBindingSource;

    NetworkDataGridView.DataSource =  NetworkBindingSource;

    ShopDataGridView.DataSource =  ShopsBindingSource;
```

all databinding is working good and synchronized, i can CUD on both grids on the Form and go to `_context.SaveChanges()` with no problem.

- **First Scenario**

a simple scenario of Pressing "+"(add) on the `NetworkBindingNavigator` and right afterwards "X"(delete) on this empty line on the grid and finally i go to `context.SaveChanges()`
succeed without a problem.

- **Second Scenario**

when i press "+"(add) on the `ShopBindingNavigator`and then right afterwards i press "X"(delete) on this empty line on the grid and finally i go to `_context.SaveChanges()` i get :

> System.Data.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: **Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Location', table 'MyDB.dbo.Shops'; column does not allow nulls**

my question is why didnt it happen in the first scenario as well (i dont allow NULL in Networks table as well) ?

Thanks.

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Why are you setting ShopsBindingSource.datasource to NetworkBindingSource? Your final exception noted "Shops" as the entity set...however NetworkBindingSource is associated with the Networks entity set...something is missing.

Comment: in databinding, when you have parent-child realationship between objects which supports databinding, and you want synchronization between them when bounded to a grid for example, you should : ParentBindingSource.datasource = <TheDataSource>; ChildBindingSource.datasource = ParentBindingSource; 

and ofcourse the final exception is noting "Shops" thats exactly the question, why does it complaint(throw exception) on the child(Shops) table and not for the futher for the same execution...

Comment: Could you check if empty Networks are inserted in DB in first scenario?

Comment: Yury: Checked,No Empty Networks are inserted to DB.

Answer (score -1):

Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Location', table 'MyDB.dbo.Shops'; column does not allow nulls means you table does not accept NULL.

so can you check in the table if the column is nullable or not. If it is not nullable then when you say it has succeeded in your first scenario have a look at you DB. Somehow you must be inputting some default values into the tables.